# how to enable containers from docker-compose "bridge" network to reach out to service running on Docker host?

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I have a `docker-compose.yml` file, that defines three services, using shared network. Network is defined only by name. `docker network list` shows that it's a `bridge` network. `docker inspect network` gives the IP addresses (`172.23.0.x`, with `172.23.0.1` defined as a gateway). My understanding is that this `gateway` is my Docker host (a Windows 10 machine).

When I execute `wget http://containerA-ip:PORT//` from `bash` running in containerB, I get response alright.

When I execute `wget http://gateway-ip:PORT//` from `bash` running in containerB, I get response alright, too. (port PORT is published as PORT:PORT, so I assume that's the reason it works).

**BUT**. If I try to `wget http://gateway-ip:OTHER-PORT`, where OTHER-PORT is a port number of some process that is listening on my Windows 10 machine, I get `Connection refused`.

I wonder, is it FW configuration on my Windows machine, that's preventing this connection, or is it some Docker configuration/implementation detail that's preventing this kind of connection.

I was unable to find an answer to "how to connect to Docker host services from within a container using `bridge` network" anywhere in the documentation..

Thanks to anyone, who could assist.

UPD: I've been suggested to check which interfaces this service is listening on, here's the output of `netstat -na | grep 8088`:

```
TCP    0.0.0.0:8088           0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING                                                                                                                      
TCP    [::]:8088              [::]:0                 LISTENING
```

to verify it's the case, I've run `curl --noproxy "*" -X POST "http://192.168.0.13:8088/"` and it produced expected response

Comment: 'Connection refused' tells you that the connection was established, but the remote host wasn't listening on the port you were trying to reach. Check if the service you are trying to reach is listening for any IP (`0.0.0.0`) and not loopback interface (`127.x.x.x`).

Comment: I've edited the question to add this information

Comment: Are you using Docker Desktop for Windows or docker-ce via WSL?

Comment: Docker Desktop, no WSL (i.e. with Hyper-V)

Comment: Try temporary disabling firewall if you still hadn't. No idea what else it could be.

Comment: On Docker Desktop (MacOS or Windows), use the special hostname `host.docker.internal`.  Don't bother looking up the container-private IP addresses.

Comment: David Maze, can you provide an answer ? THIS WORKS!!!!!!

Comment: sorry, should have used mentions: @DavidMaze